# php json_encode & newline, swift JSONSerialization causing weird output

Tags: php, ios, json, web-services, swift

Some issue with PHP JSON and Swift JSON. Please help me to figure out what is up with the extra spaces, \n and other stuff. Why is the output not a clean continuous string. I don't need to pretty print or anything.

PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM entries";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$entries = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$db = null;
echo '{"root":'.json_encode($entries).'}';
```

Swift:

```
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        var error: NSError?
        let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as? NSDictionary

        if (jsonResult != nil) {
            println(jsonResult?.description )
        } else {
            println(jsonResult?.description)
        }
```

Console Output:

```
Optional("{\n    root =     (\n                {\n            id = 1;\n            text = \"Test Entry\";\n        },\n                {\n            id = 2;\n            text = \"Test Entry 2\";\n        }\n    );\n}")
```

Database:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either do this:

```
println(jsonResult!.description)
```

Or this:

```
println(NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Comment: Instead of wrapping it in an optional, unwrap the optional (? vs !)